# Magento CSS not updating after copying site to another server

Tags: css, magento, magento-1.7, delay, updating

I done things a bit backward developing my new site, don't ask me why! But i built the site on the live server it will be hosted on first and the other day i created a sub-domain to hold a copy of the website so i can use it as a sandbox environment and test new plugins, to get PayPal working etc

[I followed this tutorial](http://wrightcreativelabs.com/create-a-test-instance-of-a-magento-store/)

So it all worked fine! i have a copy of my site on a subdomain working. I had the infamous admin login redirect to itself issue but i sorted that, the reason it wasnt working was because i had my caches disabled in magento before i copied the site. So i had to enable them again in order to gain access ( If anyone knows why this is please share).

So my problem now is, i am updating the design of my website using the css and images in the skin folder. The problem is i update something in the css and load it onto my server and into the subdomain skins folder but nothing changes on the frontend UNTIL about 15 minutes later and me clearing all caches hundreds of times!! i really don't understand whats happening?

The links to my css/js and image folders are all correct in the head of the website. It's just like a time delay between me changing something in the css and the website updating itself.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Have you also disabled cached on Magento Admin? Perhaps you can try reloading the site on a non-cached based version of browsers (e.g. Incognito Mode in Google Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is also caching the external css files which is basically good for saving bandwidth of server and reducing page loading speed. But, for development purpose, you need to avoid css caching. On firefox or IE, you can use CTRL+F5 to reload a webpage without cached css.

If you do not want to use CTRL+F5, you can also add timestamp to your css file as URL parameter.

For example, `style.css?<?php echo time();?>`

You can also use Apache module to expire the caching.

.htaccess

```
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 second"
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html

Comment: Unfortunately using ctrl F5 doesnt seem to work. IS this all the problem could posibly be? the css updates instantly on my live site and both sites are on the same server, just the dev site is in a subdomain?

Comment: Try using firebug extension of firefox and see if you can see changes right after uploading on the server.

Comment: HI Robi, i have looked within firebug and no the changes can't be seen straight away. Thanks

Comment: As you say you cant see the changes with the firebug straight away, then you have a problem with your server. You might be running out of space or less memory.. And your server might takes more time to make all the changes.. One more thing, Are you  using CDN for you site?? If yes, then you dont have any issues. Updating the CDN will take little bit of time...

Comment: I am also wondering if your server is using any other server caching. Does it have any other caching installed? Some magento optimized hosting may have their own and separate caching installed. I am not sure if that is also affecting on website.

Comment: @ Pavan Kumar  Can you tell how much time will it take to update in CDN?